# How to hide “all traffic” when plotting rows in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to look at my referral traffic over time on a per domain-basis in Google Analytics. This is what I have done:

1. Set New visits as advanced segment
2. Navigated to traffic-sources -> Referrals
3. Checked a couple of domains
4. Clicked plot rows

The individual domains now show up in the graph, but the problem is that "all traffic" is also visible. All traffic is much bigger than the graphs for individual domains. This makes it very hard to see any changes as they look all values are Zero.

Is there any way to hide "Visits" from the graph in order to zoom in on the vertical axis?

Comment: Please don't cross post on different Stack Exchange sites.  In this case, they both ended up here and cause duplicates.

Comment: Okay! Do you have any good hints as to witch SE is most suitable for a question. Both had a google analytics tag, so it's kind of hard to tell witch one is better.

Comment: Sometimes the on-topic help pages can answer that question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic  If it still isn't clear, you could try asking in chat.  It would also be fine just to post in one of the two, the question can be moved between sites by the moderators.